# Retrieve the battery drain level in Android

Tags: java, android, battery

I have seen that some applications show the amount of mV/hour the battery is consuming. Is there a way of retrieving that info? Or those programs are periodically reading the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intent,recording the voltage level and calculating the gradient?

Comment: I would say the latter - it's computed. This is just a guess thou, but I would assume that actual battery drain would differ to much from each reading to be of any value. Even if possible - the calculated value would make much more sense and be the most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

getting the battery information

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()  {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {          
     int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0); 
         System.out.println("battery level" + level);            
  }
};
```